# How do I reference another documents data by objectID?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a page that contains an id in the URL. I want to use this ID to filter my db query to only give me results that contain an object that contains the url ID.

Here is my db setup:

[image]

I want to only return CHARITY results that have the CAUSE id.

Here is how I'm trying to do it but something isn't right.

```
 findCharities: function(req, res) {
  db.Charity
   .find()
   .where("charities.cause").equals(req.body.id) 
   .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
   .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
},
```

Any idea how to update this query so that I can filter correctly?

Comment: Where did you find this syntax? The proper `find` syntax for mongoose is: `Model.find({cause: req.body.id}).then(...)`

Comment: I put what you said "  .find({cause: req.body.id})" and it still doesn't filter. Is this because the cause is defined in the charity Model as Schema.Types.ObjectId?

Comment: You can try `Model.find({cause: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id)}).then(...)`. If you get a cast error, that means your `req.body.id` is not properly set to an object id.